# ionic - Firebase issue

Tags: firebase, npm, ionic3

Getting the following error while creating the build.Else not having any problem.
Any solutions to resolve this issue.

Currently using following congfiguration...'

```
 "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "angular-bottom-sheet": "^1.2.5",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.20",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^7.6.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.5",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.2",
    "typescript": "3.2.2"
  },
```

I got an error blow, please find it:

```
[20:15:04]  typescript: ...e_m_pwd_app/e_i/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/src/api/Database.d.ts, line: 44
            An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

      L43:  * We throw a exception if the url is not in the same domain as the
      L44:  * current repo.
      L45:  * @param {string} url

[20:15:04]  typescript: ...m_pwd_app/e_i/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/src/api/DataSnapshot.d.ts, line: 88
            An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.


[20:15:04]  typescript: ...m_pwd_app/e_i/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/src/api/DataSnapshot.d.ts, line: 98
            An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.


[20:15:04]  typescript: ...nd/e_p/e_i/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/src/api/Query.d.ts, line: 36
            An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

      L36:   * Validates that no other order by call has been made
      L37:   * @param {!string} fnName

[20:15:04]  typescript: ...nd/e_p/e_i/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/src/api/Query.d.ts, line: 37
            An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

      L36:  * Validates that no other order by call has been made
      L37:  * @param {!string} fnName
      L38:  * @private
```

i am working with firebase database with ionic framework. when i trying to connect with firebase i am getting above mentioned error in ionic framework,
please give me a solution for this issue.

Comment: Hi Prince, welcome to StackOverflow. This question will need to be edited and reformatted to be easily readable. As the question currently stands, it is unlikely to get a positive response. I'd highly recommend reading through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

please check the keyname firebase as well as your code (fnName). please share your code

Comment: Thanks,got it resolved.Just replace the index.d.ts with the given below link code.  [link](https://gist.github.com/PRINCEHR/992de6660978c84c0a9f54256eb58d74)